# ExpectedSystemExit is causing the error

Tags: java, junit, system-rules

I'm using the library [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/) to testing method that calls System.exit():

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedSystemExit exit = ExpectedSystemExit.none();
```

Unfortunately, this piece of code is causing the error ...

```
initializationError caused an ERROR: org/junit/rules/TestRule
```

I'm using JUnit 4.7 and System Rules 1.2.0.

Comment: Could you post more of your class. I'm using SystemRules just like this and everything seems to be fine.

Comment: I suspect, that the issue of my problem may be configuration of NetBeans, but I added appropriate jar files to "Test libraries".

Answer (score 2):

System Rules needs at least version 4.9 of JUnit.

(I add this information to System Rules' homepage. Thank you for posting your question.)

Answer (score 0):

System Rules seems to want the following dependencies

- junit-4.11-beta-1

hth

Comment: I added hamcrest-core-1.3.jar to "Test Libraries" but the problem still exists. This must be a mistake in my configuration of Netbeans, because it does not work properly even for very simple classes.

Comment: The issue of my problem was JUnit 4.7. Using version 4.11, everything works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool.  I didn't run into any of these headaches because I'm using Maven, and it just figures everything out (mostly) for you. :)